# mod_rewrite log with referers?

Tags: mod-rewrite, logging

"mod_rewrite" does logging itself via "RewriteLogLevel" and "RewriteLog". I'm wondering if I can get it to capture the referring URL in the logs when it executes a redirect.

Alternatively, does mod_rewrite add any environment variables when something gets redirected? If so, I could use that to create a custom log using "mod_log_config".

Answer (score 0):

The [mod_rewrite Debug Tutorial at AskApache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html) should provide a solid foundation for just about any kind of logging you'd want to implement.